# android TimerTask keeps adding infinite items to listview

Tags: android, arrays, timertask

I am working on a project that fetches data from a server and displays the data on a listview for the user to see t
his works fine but after introducing a Timer task to refresh content of the listview i get a long infinite repeat of the contents. here is a screenshot and the code am using:

```
package com.example.pius;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class viewChat extends Activity {
// ArrayList of type "Person". We are making not a list of string, sondern eine list of persons
    ArrayList<Person> arrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<Person>();
class Person{
    public String message;
    public String name;
    public String time;
    //public String last_m;
}
//update stuffs
Timer autoUpdate;

// This is our new Adapter:
    FancyAdapter aa = null;

    // For each row we returned until we use the array to create our person obj
    static ArrayList<String> resultRow;

Intent i;
String rName,recId,myName;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);
    new getChat().execute();
}

//getting your getting chat with a user from server

    // Params,Progress,Result
        private class getChat extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
        {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                String result = "";
                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/someparams");
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
                    // Convert response to String:
                    try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;

                        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                            sb.append(line+"\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        result = sb.toString();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Parse JSON:
                try{
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for(int i = 0;i < jArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        // Get our object, this is on persons data:
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Create a new person:
                        Person resultRow = new Person();
                        // Set thats persons attributes:
                        resultRow.message = json_data.getString("mmm");
                        resultRow.name = json_data.getString("sss");
                        resultRow.time = json_data.getString("ttt");
                        //resultRow.birthday = json_data.getString("pix");
                        arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
                    }   
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;    
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                populateListView();
            }   
        }


        public void populateListView()
        {
            final ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.onepm);
            // initialite FancyAdapter object:
            aa = new FancyAdapter();


            myListView.setAdapter(aa);  

            //click action for each list
            myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
                {
                    // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
                    //Person p = (Person) myListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want
                    //Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.person_id);

                    // Do something with the data. For example, passing them to a new Activity
                    //when message is tapped
                }
            }); 




        }


        class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person>
        {
            FancyAdapter(){
                super(viewChat.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfWebData);
                //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
            }
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final ViewHolder holder;
                if(convertView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row4, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                    convertView.setTag(holder); 
                }else{
                    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));
                arrayOfWebData.clear();
                return convertView; 
            }
        }

        class ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView name = null;
            public TextView message = null;
            //public TextView time = null;
            //public TextView favorite_color = null;


            ViewHolder(View row){

                name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.opname);
                message = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dmessage);
                //last_m = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lmess);  
            }
            // Notice we have to change our populateFrom() to take an argument of type "Person"
            void populateFrom(Person r){
                if("you".equals(r.name)){
                    //message.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)message.getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(80, 0, 0, 0);
                message.setLayoutParams(params);
                message.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#98ccff"));
                }else{
                    //message.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)message.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(0, 0, 80, 0);
                    message.setLayoutParams(params);
                    message.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffcc98"));
                }
                //attempt to bring html to life
                String hdtext = r.message;
                Spanned ftext = Html.fromHtml(hdtext);
               // name.setText(r.name);
                message.setText(ftext);
                //last_m.setText(r.last_m);
                //favorite_color.setText(r.favorite_color); 
            }   
        }
        //auto refresh
        @Override
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            autoUpdate = new Timer();
            autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            new getChat().execute();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0,300);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Hey here is another solution for updating listview at every desired time

-Create you handler and `private Handler yourhandler=new Handler();
        Runnable yourrunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new YourASynctask.execute();
            }
        };
yourhandler.post(yourrunnable);`

-In your **Postexecute** method of your *Asynctask*
paste below code `yourhandler.postDelayed(yourrunnable, 2000);`

-Where  ***2000*** is your desired time 
-Just put my above code into **onresume** method and. 
-In Your code clear your array before you add to it .

```
try{


 arrayweb.clear();

for(...)
```

{

```
arrayweb.add(obj);
```

}

}

Thanks Vote my answer if you find it useful and if you still get stuck please let me inform!

Comment: Tried your first answer nothing is displayed for some seconds then app has stopped working error.

Comment: here i created another asyntask to handle refresh in that new async i replaced arrayOfWebData with updatedData and then call getChat().execute in the onCreate and refreshChat.execute in TimerTask the result this time is that the data will be displayed as the app launch, then disappear when timerTask executes

Comment: and can you please help with a more practical code of solution 2? like  how to implement it to my work. thanks

Comment: Thanks! Added arrayOfWebData.clear() inside the try and just before the for loop. Worked the magic. Thanks! Though am having another issue. The refresh asynctask makes it impossible for my app to send another asyntask json request! Any help on that?

Comment: You can send me the code snippet and Line number at which you are getting Isuue :)